# Import and classes confusion

Tags: function, class, python-2.7

If I have a file called init.py:

```
class main:
    import foo
    import bar
```

and another file called foo.py, how can I import init's "main" class? Because I've seen this working instead of classes with functions, and it is a bit confusing, how classes and functions rank.

e.g.: if i import bar, what I am importing, the class or the file? if I want to import the class? and what about calling a function inside the class?

Comment: `from init import main`?

Comment: Why does `init.py` carry out the `import`s *inside* the class?

Comment: @jonsharpe because it imports all the needed modules for being DRY and not writing it in each different module.

Comment: @paulgriffiths and i get main. So if I define a function inside, it would be main.bar(), isn't it?

Comment: @JuanRocamonde: If it was a class method. If it's an instance method, obviously you'd need to instantiate a `main` object first.

Comment: @JuanRocamonde you should `import` at the top level. If `main.bar` doesn't need access to instance attributes it doesn't need to be in a class; Python isn't Java or .NET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case:

```
# foo.py

import string

class Bar(object):
    ...

def baz(...):
    ...
```

You have two choices:

1. Using `import foo` would bring `foo` into your namespace, giving access to `foo.Bar` and `foo.baz`; or
2. You could e.g. `from foo import baz` to bring `baz` directly into the namespace, so you can access it without needing `foo.`.

Note that you can have both classes and functions at the top level, which is also where `import`s should be done.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a file called `Foo.py`, and inside that file you defined a class called `Foo`, like this.

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, args):
        # perform initialization
```

Now you want to use this class in a different file called `main.py`, which we will assume for simplicity is in the same directory. You have two options.

The first option is to use `import Foo`, and then refer to the class by `Foo.Foo`.

```
import Foo
myFoo = Foo.Foo(args)
```

The second option is to write `from Foo import Foo`, and refer to the class by `Foo`.

```
from Foo import Foo
myFoo = Foo(args)
```